# Determine comma or dot as decimal seperator in Visual Studio (SSIS Tools)

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2017-build-tools, ssis-2017

In my SSIS project I'm running a calculation. This calculation changes the decimal seperator according to the users regional settings.

My question is if there's anyway to override this so I can select that this project or this package is supposed to run with a specified regional setting?

I've tried changing the LocaleID on recommendations from other sources I could find but it didn't help.

My environment:

Visual Studio 2017
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) Version 15.9.19.
Windows 2016 10.0.14393 Build 14393

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you bring in the column as a string and then replace commas to decimals and then convert that string to a decimal?

Comment: Unfortunately there's a lot of packages that needs to be changed for this. If some uses use different regional settings it displays it differently. In our case we need to override this on a package level as we have many projects this needs to be changed for and rewriting the column as a string and replacing the commas to decimals would require a lot of time. If there was an easier way such as defining this parameter on the package it would be ideal.